# PHP : how to draw italic ou bold text in image?

Tags: php, image, gd

Php has 2 functions to draw text in image : imagettftext and imagestring

Is it possible to draw bold or italic text in image with theses functions ?

Comment: `bold` and `italic` are actually **different** fonts completely. You could just use the `.ttf` file for the bold/italic version of the font

Comment: Infact, it's exactly how the solution in the duplicate does it. See `$usernameBox = imagettfbbox($textSize, 0, './arialbd.ttf', $usernameTotal);` which is his bold text and `$whiteSpaceBox = imagettfbbox($textSize, 0, './arial.ttf', $whiteSpace);` which is his normal text

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Right, however they asked for "or", so I closed it off with a duplicate.

Comment: Another find: https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/php-gd-writing-bold-italic-text.31273/

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yeah I'm not arguing the cause for the reason of close, I think it was a right call. The OP of the previous answer did a sucky job explaining the solution so I thought I'd just go in depth slightly here

Comment: @IsThisJavascript you did good on explaining ;-)